# How do you integrate $\frac{2x}{\lambda^2}e^{-\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^2}$ over $x > 0$?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I am currently trying to solve this problem, but I have no idea where to start as there are two unknown variables $x$ and $\lambda$ in the function body.

I think that there might be some identity that I am unaware of in order to condense this expression into a simpler one to integrate.

Comment: Make the substitution $y=(\frac x {\lambda})^{2}$

Comment: Sick! Thanks @geetha290krm, I'll try that out.

Comment: Hi @geetha290krm, I have done the substitution, and I'm at $\frac{2x}{\lambda^2}e^{-y^2}$. I can't figure out how to carry on from this point - would you be so kind to assist me?

Comment: geetha is suggesting that you perform a $u$-substitution, so you also need to consider $dy = \dots $. Write out the entire integral including the $dx$.

Comment: Thank you so much @geetha290krm and Qiaochu Yuan! I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that $\lambda$ is a constant. The derivative with respect to $x$
of $\exp\left(-x^2/\lambda^2\right)$ is, up to a minus sign, the function you have to integrate.

Comment: Thanks Davide! I think that is where my understanding fell short. I really appreciate your response! Thanks so much.